# Install specific version and arch, without specifying the release

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, rpm

Assume I want to install the `glibc-devel` package with version `2.17` and `i686` arch. Assume I don't care about the specific [release](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#what-is-a-spec-file).

Assume as well that this is being run from a script, such that `yum --showduplicates list` and similar solutions are not possible.

- If I did not care about the arch, I could run `yum install glibc-devel-2.17` and I would get the current release for the 2.17 version of glibc-devel with the x86_64 arch.
- If I did not care about the version, I could run `yum install glibc-devel.i686` and get the most recent version and release of glibc-devel with the i686 arch.

But if I try to run `yum install glibc-devel-2.17.i686` yum tells me that `No package glibc-devel-2.17.i686 available.`.

How can I constrain both the version and the arch of a package, without knowing the actual release?

(glibc-devel is only an example, this is a generic question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use globs:

```
yum install glibc-devel-2.17-*.i686
```

`yum` only supports architecture specifications combined with either only a package name, or a full version and release (and optionally, epoch).

With `dnf`, you could use the `--arch` or `--forcearch` options instead.